# ASP.Net MVC Model wont bind on ajax post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble getting a model to bind on my action when I post from ajax (via jquery).

Model:

```
public class NoteEditViewModel 
{
    public bool AddMode { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }        

    public NoteEditViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

Action:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Edit(NoteEditViewModel note)
 {
     ...
 }
```

JS:  (actually typescript)

```
 $.ajax({
    url: this.options.editUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(this.convertFormToJSON(this.options.noteFormElement)),
    //data: $(this.options.noteFormElement).serialize(),
    //data: JSON.stringify({
    //  AddMode: $("#AddMode").val(),
    //  ID: $("#ID").val(),
    //  PersonID: $("#PersonID").val(),
    //  Note: $("#Note").val()
    //}),
    //dataType: 'json',
    //traditional:true,
    //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: (partialResult) => {
      this.options.noteModalElement.modal('hide');
    }
  });

convertFormToJSON(form : JQuery) {
  var array = form.serializeArray();
  var json = {};

  jQuery.each(array, function () {
    json[this.name] = this.value || '';
  });

  return json;
}
```

You can see what I've tried here.  The action would either receive an empty instance of the model or null.

I did managed to get this to work with a custom ModelBinder, thus:

```
 public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var body = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[0];
        var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NoteEditViewModel>(body);
        return model;
    }
```

This may not be the best/safest, but at least it works.

I cant see what I've done wrong here but creating a model binder for each model seems crazy.  Non-ajax posts seem to work fine.

Thanks

Comment: Try `data: JSON.stringify({ note:  this.convertFormToJSON(this.options.noteFormElement})),`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a custom `ModelBinder`. Your values will be successfully submitted using

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.options.editUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: (partialResult) => {
      this.options.noteModalElement.modal('hide');
    }
});
```

The reason your model is not binding in the POST method is because the name of your parameter (`note`) is also the name of a property in your model and the `DefaultModelBinder` sets the value of property `Note` to the posted value, but also attempts to set the instance of `NoteEditViewModel` to that value (a `string`) which fails and the model becomes `null`

Change the signature of the method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(NoteEditViewModel model)
```

and you model will be correctly bound

Comment: OMG.  I should have guessed it was something stupid/simple like that.  Ive been thrashing on this for days.   I owe you beer!  :)

Comment: Wow - I read this answer and ignored it and finally came back and actually read it for comprehension and yes it is exactly the issue I've been having :face_palm: